# Validate Rule Doesn't Throw Syntax Error But Doesn't Throw Errors Either

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I'm trying to run an Account Validation Rule where if the Account Status Equals Closed, Users cannot update the Account. System Admin Profile is allowed to edit.   There aren't any syntax errors on save, however, when I log in as a non-admin, I'm still able to edit an Account when it's closed.  What's going on here?

ps) We must use custom labels.

`AND( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Account_Status__c),"Closed"), 
NOT($Profile.Name == "System Administrator"), 
($RecordType.Name == $Label.Account_Record_Type) 
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRIORVALUE` means when you change the fields value, itll return the old value. Its used for validation when you change a field. If you dont change the field, but the value of the field is still "Closed", your rule will fail to trigger.

You probably want something like this:

Cant edit closed accounts unless an admin:

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Account_Status__c,"Closed"), 
    NOT($Profile.Name == "System Administrator"), 
    ($RecordType.Name == $Label.Account_Record_Type) 
)
```

This sample shows that you can configure your formula to fire even if a user changes the status, or if the status is already closed.

```
AND( 
    OR (
        ISPICKVAL(Account_Status__c,"Closed"), 
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Account_Status__c),"Closed")
    ),
    NOT($Profile.Name == "System Administrator"), 
    ($RecordType.Name == $Label.Account_Record_Type) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you! One change I had to make was using "RecordType.DeveloperName" instead of "RecordType.Name" 
`($RecordType.DeveloperName= $Label.Account_Record_Type)`
 The rule didn't trigger until I made that last change